Inf-sup expression for the smallest singular value
I've encountered a question about the singular value:
If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $\sigma_1(A)\geq \cdots \geq \sigma_{n}(A) = \sigma_{\min(A)} > 0 $, then
$$
\sigma_{\min}(A) = \inf_{u\in\mathbb{R}^n}\sup_{v\in\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{v^TAu}{\|v\|_2\|u\|_2}.\tag{1}
$$
My effort:
By the Min max Theorem for singular values, I know there is an expression in the form of subspace:
$$
\sigma_{i}(A) = \min_{\dim(U)=n-i+1}\max_{\stackrel{x\in U}{\|x\|_2=1}} \|Ax\|_2,
$$
but I can't deduce the equation (1).

I voted to close this question because it is just a direct application of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $\sup\limits_{v\ne0}\dfrac{v^TAu}{|v|_2|u|_2}=\dfrac{|Au|_2}{|u|_2}$.

Since $\sigma_{\min}(A)> 0$, then we can let $v = Au$, then $\sup_{v\neq 0}\frac{v^TAu}{|v|_2|u|_2} = \frac{|Au|_2}{|u|_2}$, right?
